# Effectively mock a global property with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, jasmine, google-api-js-client

My app has dependencies to gapi javascript client (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js) and jsapi (https://www.google.com/jsapi).

I building my app with AngularJS and using Karma (formerly Testacular) as a Test runner.

I managed to effectively mock them by loading them in Karma and next spying some methods:

```
it('should call gapi on share', inject(function (config, doc) {
        config.appId = 'testAppId';

        var shareClientMock = {
            setItemIds: jasmine.createSpy('setItemIds'),
            showSettingsDialog: jasmine.createSpy('showSettingsDialog')
        };
        spyOn(gapi.drive.share, 'ShareClient').andReturn(shareClientMock);

        scope.share();

        expect(gapi.drive.share.ShareClient).toHaveBeenCalledWith(config.appId);
        expect(shareClientMock.setItemIds).toHaveBeenCalledWith([doc.info.id]);
        expect(shareClientMock.showSettingsDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

I would like to mock them, without actually including it, with Jasmine but I can figure out how.
I tried by creating a stub in beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(function () { window.gapi = {...} });
```

But it is still undefined.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Placing @SpoBo's comment as an answer, as it fixed my problem:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  angular.mock.module('moduleName', $provide => {
    $provide.decorator('$window', $delegate => {
      $delegate.gapi = {
        auth2: {
          getAuthInstance: null,
        },
        // ... or whatever else you need to mock
      };
      return $delegate;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use the injector to get the $window provider, then you can add the mocks to that object.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
   window = $injector.get('$window');
   window.gapi = {...};
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You should use a decorator for this before the inject. Aka in the module with the $provider. ```module('module', function($provide) {
            $provide.decorator('$window', function($delegate) {
                $delegate.gapi = {...};
                return $delegate;
            });
        });```

Comment: @SpoBo, your comment really helped me, and i wish it was more visible.  I wish you would post it as an answer, it deserves some upvotes.

Comment: Go ahead and make an answer out of it yourself if you want. Glad it helped you. The dependency injector is very useful during test.

Comment: @SpoBo, I took your info and j.wittwer's advice. It's not an answer. Feel free to edit. Thanks for the help!